# Больше информации по делегатам, событиям, лямбдам и тд

Tags: c#, события, делегаты

Ребята, буду рад если скинете ссылку на более углубленную информацию (технически) о делегатах и тд.

P.S. Гуглить могу, возможно кто то знает хорошую статью/книгу

Comment: Без сарказма: msdn очень объёмно, и детально .

Comment: Посмотрите здесь(хорошие видеоуроки). Несколько раз перестматривал, когда сам разбирался:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uI3rZYk2sYk